# jQuery interactive cartoons?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am thinking about starting one new project, which basically will be web site containing interactive amination (like interactive comics books), something similar to this: http://www.ipadforums.net/ipad-apps/82532-interactive-cartoon-abc-your-childs-first-steps-reading.html

The main thing is that it should be available for tablets, including iPads - basically this is the main target auditory.

Average length of each cartoon supposed to be about 10 minutes, and they should play audio files as well.

My questions: 
 - Would it be really slow if made only with JavaScript/jQuery/HTML?
 - What is the best way to insert audio files? Some plugins?

Comment: Depends how complex you need it to be. If you don't need legacy support, then HTML5 `<canvas>` and `<audio>` should be able to handle everything. If you're doing something simpler, a few `<div>` elements and some `<audio>` can be manipulated by jQuery without being slow.

Comment: Well about complexity - as I sad it would look like animated comics which I believe is a changing background image and couple of active 'heroes'. The thing is that it should play alternative scenarios based on user actions and it would require user interactions frequently.